# can there be a case when some php files work on lamp and not on wamp?

Tags: wamp, lamp

I mean,technically it shouldnt matter because i use PHP 5.3.0 in both cases...but there's this php file which when executed gives me the output correctly on Linux..but just displays the html part when i execute on windows...

Comment: I'd check the php.ini files to make sure that they had the same (or similar) parameters.  I'd also check the httpd.conf file on the Windows computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the php file for incorrect filesystem paths.

> but just displays the html part when i execute on windows

Assuming you mean it displays that code instead of the php output, make sure that this file starts and ends with the proper php tags...

```
<?php
?>
```

Some servers have short tags option on, some don't.